# Cursor disappears when TextField.selectable = false;

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

Cursor disappears when

```
TextField.selectable = false;
```

How can I make cursor to be visible but textfield not selectable(with mouse) or CTRL+A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen a similar problem in the past, but I don't remember how to duplicate it.  It no longer appears in the project I first saw it in, so the two things which I know have happened since then are below.  Of course, there could be some other variable, but the project is working now...

I suspect that the field is still editable.  That would be my first guess.  The first thing I would try then:

```
//( in a flash.text object ( Flash or Flex ) )
myTxtFld.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;

//( in a mx.controls object ( Flex ) )
myTxtFld.editable = false;
```

If that does not work, try nesting the TextField in something with a MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER listener and useHandCursor set to False.  eg:

```
var spt:Sprite = new Sprite();
spt.useHandCursor = false;
spt.addChild( myTxtFld );
spt.addEventListener( MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, function( anon:* ){} );
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe flash/as3 sees the text cursor as a zero width selection, I dont see how it should be possible to do what you want to here, except maybe extending textfield and placing your own cursor on mouseevents